# I want to make binding in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I'm trying to make control to add contacts Which has a TreeView. When I add contacts to the control displays nothing in the treeView. Here I show the code:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TvContactos" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Left"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"> 
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelGroupContact}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <Grid Height="35">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName}" Style="{StaticResource BloStyle}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelContact}">
                <Grid Height="38">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Height="32" Width="32" Source="Resources/User.jpg" Margin="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactName}" Style="{StaticResource BloStyle}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </TreeView.Resources>
            <TreeView.DataContext>
                <local:ViewModelGroups/>
            </TreeView.DataContext>
        </TreeView.Resources>
```

In the code behind I have the following classes

```
public class ViewModelGroups : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    ObservableCollection<ViewModelGroupContact> _groups;

    public ViewModelGroups()
    {
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelGroupContact>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelGroupContact> Groups
    {
        get { return _groups; }
        set
        {
            _groups = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
        }
    }

    public void AddGroup(string groupName,RosterItem contact)
    {
        var newContact = new Contact {Name = contact.Name ?? contact.Jid.ToString(), RosterItem = contact};
        var vmc = _groups.FirstOrDefault(item => item.GroupName == groupName);
        if (vmc == null)
        {
            var contGroup = new ContactGroup { Name = groupName };
            vmc = new ViewModelGroupContact(contGroup);
        }
        vmc.AddContactToGroup(newContact);
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((new Action(() => Groups.Add(vmc))));
        OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class ViewModelGroupContact : TreeViewItemViewModel

{
    private readonly ContactGroup _contactGroup;

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public ViewModelGroupContact(ContactGroup contactGroup)
        : base(null, true)
    {
        _contactGroup = contactGroup;
        GroupName = _contactGroup.Name;
    }

    protected override void LoadChildren()
    {
        foreach (Contact contact in _contactGroup.GetContacts())
            base.Children.Add(new ViewModelContact(contact, this));
    }

    public void AddContactToGroup(Contact contact)
    {
        if (!_contactGroup.GetContacts().Contains(contact))
            _contactGroup.AddContactToGroup(contact);
    }
}

public class ViewModelContact:TreeViewItemViewModel
{
    private readonly Contact _contact;

    public ViewModelContact(Contact contact, ViewModelGroupContact group)
        : base(group, true)
    {
        _contact = contact;
    }

    public string ContactName
    {
        get { return _contact.Name; }
    }
}
```

When added a contact to treeview nothing is displayed.No show TreeViewItemViewModel class which inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged for not doing longer the post. This class has a property called Childrens.

This is the control class that was missing

```
public partial class ContactControl : UserControl
{
    #region Private

    private ViewModelGroups _viewModel;

    private const string MDefaultGroupName = "ungrouped";

    #endregion
    public ContactControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    public ViewModelGroups ViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel; }
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        _viewModel = new ViewModelGroups();
        TvContactos.DataContext = _viewModel;
    }

    public void AddContact(RosterItem ritem)
    {
        string groupname;
        if (ritem.GetGroups().Count > 0)
        {
            var g = (Group)ritem.GetGroups().Item(0);
            groupname = g.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            groupname = MDefaultGroupName;
        }
        _viewModel.AddGroup(groupname, ritem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you something initially? Also are you sure you're adding to `Children`? For example `AddContactToGroup` adds to `_contactGroup` only but does not refresh/update `Children` collection

Comment: Yes, in the control's constructor initializes the DataContext treeview.                                                                   public ContactControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init();
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            _viewModel = new ViewModelGroups();
            TvContactos.DataContext = _viewModel;
        }

Comment: and what about `AddContactToGroup`? does it add at some point to `Children` collection as well?

Comment: The Children property is loaded when the method LoadChildren() is called. I tested this code loading the Groups property from the constructor of the class ViewModelGroups and the treeview displays data. Data are not shown when the Groups property is updated from the method AddGroup () of class ViewModelGroups

Comment: ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" I do not see this property in your ViewModelGroupContact class. Where is this coming from?